# How can I make a string from two strings with the common and uncommon words in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried with this but the code returns the common words only. But I want the output from bottom two variables like this "Warfarin 5 mg Tablet, Syrup".

```
$string1 = "Warfarin 5 mg Tablet";
$string2 = "Warfarin 5 mg Syrup";
    
function show_unique_strings($a, $b) {
    $aArray = explode(" ",$a);
    $bArray = explode(" ",$b);
    $intersect = array_intersect($aArray, $bArray);
    $str = implode(" ", array_merge(array_diff($aArray, $intersect), array_diff($bArray, $intersect)));
    return $str;
}
                
return show_unique_strings($string1, $string2);
```

Comment: Are those strings dynamic or constant?

Comment: Your question lacks clarity. Please support it with some more examples.

Comment: Dynamic. the strings will come from db. I just gave an example.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  What do you expect it to do with two strings "warfarin 5 mg Syrup" and "rosuvastatin 5 mg tablet"?  The code you describe, when fixed, will do something like "5 mg warfarin syrup, rosuvastatin tablet".  I think you need to describe your objective a bit more clearly.  As already commented, so more examples would probably help.  Also take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - its got some good advice as to how to get a quick and helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

lets say two strings are `"Warfarin 5 mg Tablet"` and `"Warfarin 5 mg Syrup"`

```
$string1 = "Warfarin 5 mg Tablet";
$string2 = "Warfarin 5 mg Syrup";

$diff = array_diff(explode(" ", $string2), explode(" ", $string1));
$get = current($diff);
$response = $string1.', '.$get;
```

but again I asking are those strings constant or dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the word-count is the same across all Strings:

```
function show_unique_strings(...$strings) {
    $stringsAsArray = array_map(fn ($string) => explode(' ', $string), $strings);
    $countWords = count($stringsAsArray[0]);
    
    $resultArray = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $countWords; $i++) {
        $words = array_unique(array_column($stringsAsArray, $i));
        
        $resultArray[] = implode(', ', $words);
    }
    
    return implode(' ', $resultArray);
}
```

Code in words:

- We convert every supplied string to an array via `explode` within `array_map`.
- Then we count how many words the first String has (`count` on exploded string).
- For every word-position `array_column` at `$i` we then get only the uniques `array_unique` - this way we get an array for unique words for position `$i` across all strings.
- We join this array using `implode` and save it in an array `$resultArray`
- Finally we join `$resultArray` likewiese and return it.

Working example: https://3v4l.org/BlFWW